# Equivalent to Riemann Hypothesis

Tags: soft-question, analytic-number-theory, riemann-hypothesis

Through last number theory, I did learn that Riemann hypothesis is equivalent to the following inequality : $|\pi(x)-Li(x)| \leq \sqrt{x} log(x)$ where $Li(x)$ is the Logarithmic integral function and $\pi(x)$ is the prime-counting function.
So, I have been more interested in it, i'd like to know more conditions which are equivalent to Riemann Hypothesis

Please, Let me know that.

Comment: Do you know how to prove it is equivalent, or at least implies RH ? See this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1863015/prime-number-theorem-and-the-riemann-zeta-function/1863189#1863189) and this [Collection of equivalent forms of Riemann Hypothesis](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/39944/collection-of-equivalent-forms-of-riemann-hypothesis) on mathoverflow

Comment: I don't know if in previous collections (those cited by users in comments and answer) were some due to **Sondow**, **van de Lune** and **Nazardonyavi**. You are welcome if in next seasons you need I write such references. I believe that the more important is the genuine complex version itself, learn the relationship between primes and non-trivial zeros. It is a problem of cross-cutting nature (a time ago I've heard in a talk, that is a  *transalgebraic* issue). Also there are questions in the interface between mathematics and physics. All previous my claims are from a divulgative viewpoint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Online lists of equivalents of the Riemann hypothesis include:

http://aimath.org/WWN/rh/  (section C, "Equivalences to RH")

http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/mrwatkin/zeta/RHreformulations.htm

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis#Criteria_equivalent_to_the_Riemann_hypothesis

Comment: A list at MathOverflow, cited in the comments under the question.   http://mathoverflow.net/questions/39944/collection-of-equivalent-forms-of-riemann-hypothesis